# Auto-refresh references in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, asp.net

Consider the following:

I have a .NET 3.5 project that uses a .NET 1.1 dll.  When I copy the 1.1 dll into the location referenced by the 3.5 project, the 3.5 project will not compile until I close out Visual Studio and reopen the project.  I think this is related to refreshing the reference to the 1.1 dll but I'd like a setting to auto-refresh the references.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "will not compile"?

Comment: It won't compile...as in I rebuild the project and have build errors.

Comment: What exception(s) does it throw?

Comment: I'm guessing some exception that would not provide any context to this question, but tells @Achillies that the project is running an old version of the DLL.

Comment: No...it will not run period.  Not even launch the debugger.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried using a [.refresh file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fdbs127%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)?  Here is a snippet from Microsoft's documentation:

> In Visual Studio .NET, referenced
>   assemblies (for example, assemblies
>   that are referenced outside of the
>   solution in which the Web project is
>   located) could have the CopyLocal
>   property set to true, which would
>   automatically update the referenced
>   assembly. In Visual Studio 2005, this
>   behavior is replaced by creating a
>   refresh file in the Bin folder. The
>   refresh file contains the path to the
>   external referenced assembly and has
>   the extension .refresh appended to the
>   assembly name.

Sounds like it would solve your problem.  Also, have you tried just setting "CopyLocal" to false for the assembly that isn't updating.

Comment: This link has a better explanation of how to use .refresh files http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsgeneral/thread/1be24ea7-1e99-4594-b944-d96fde628722/.